# How can I have maven copy fat jar to a directory as part of a maven build?

Tags: java, maven, jar, copy

I've created a jar with all of the dependencies using the `maven-shade-plugin`.  The resulting jar I'd like to install in to a directory based on an environment variable.  For instance, something like `$SITE_HOME/container`.  Additionally, I'd like to call the command to do this work using the normal maven command, so something like:

`%> mvn copy`

or

`%> mvn package:copy`

or something, I'm not sure what works best with maven because I'm fairly new to maven.

The idea though is that I ONLY want the fat jar, I don't want resource/ or dependencies for the project, or anything other than the resulting fat jar.  How can I do this with maven, and hopefully without having to write my own maven plugin.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your needs you could use this:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html

You can embed that inside a Maven phase callin' it automatically when you call the phase you choose..

here you can see the usage:

(copy artifacts)http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-artifacts.html
(copy dependencies)http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-project-dependencies.html

```
    <project>
     [...]
     <build>
     <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.8</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/alternateLocation</outputDirectory>
              <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
              <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
              <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

I hope this helps..